# My ISP set up a PTR record for my mail server, but some places aren't seeing it

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I have a VPS running Windows 2008 server with plesk 9, which I am using for email. I asked to my ISP to add a PTR record, which they did but my mails still droping into spam box.

I have checked almost every DNS tool I can think of, and sometimes it shows the PTR record and sometime it does not.  I'm not sure where the problem is.

This morning and all day intodns was showing i have a reverse ptr but right now not. 
Could anyone point me to the right direction to find out where is the problem.
Thanks a lot.

http://www.intodns.com/wcrop.com

```
81.222.137.195.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected
```

Comment: How recently was it added? There's a negative TTL associated with each zone. You might just need to wait a few hours.

Comment: They added more than a week ago.

Comment: +1 for having the common sense to tell us what DNS record was causing the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is funky with your ISP's DNS.

There are two authoritative nameservers for `222.137.195.in-addr.arpa.`:

```
222.137.195.in-addr.arpa. 172800 IN NS  ns2.lermi.net.
222.137.195.in-addr.arpa. 172800 IN NS  ns1.lermi.net.
```

These two servers are out of sync: NS1 has zone serial 1334308835 and is returning your PTR record.  NS2 has zone serial 1330809486 (older), and is not returning your PTR record.
Anyone whose query is (randomly) sent to NS2 will not get your PTR record.

Instruct your ISP to fix this issue and all should be right in your DNS universe.

---

**NS1**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> @ns1.lermi.net -x 195.137.222.81
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48514
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;81.222.137.195.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
81.222.137.195.in-addr.arpa. 172800 IN  PTR wcrop.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
222.137.195.in-addr.arpa. 172800 IN SOA tr1.turkcealan.com. log\@ramtek.net.tr. 1334308835 10800 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 149 msec
;; SERVER: 195.149.85.195#53(195.149.85.195)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 19 18:26:23 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 68
```

**NS2**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> @ns2.lermi.net -x 195.137.222.81
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 50379
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;81.222.137.195.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
222.137.195.in-addr.arpa. 172800 IN SOA tr1.turkcealan.com. log\@ramtek.net.tr. 1330809486 10800 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 145 msec
;; SERVER: 195.137.223.65#53(195.137.223.65)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 19 18:26:51 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 140
```

Comment: I know that you're on a windows machine, but I got the nameservers (and most of the other information) by using the `dig` command on a unix box.  There are similar/equivalent tools for Windows.

Comment: I will speak with them asap.

Comment: i wish, i was on unix but dont know so much tools on windows nslookup does not give that much information. Mostly i used online tools.

Comment: @Dali I don't know any online tools that are anywhere near as useful as `dig`.  There are [version of `dig` for Windows](http://members.shaw.ca/nicholas.fong/dig/) though, and the [manual page from any Unix distribution](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dig&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) should give you a good idea of how to use it...

Comment: I just got dig nicely work. Thank you for helping.